# 先に読み込んだ文字列の前に文字列を挿入したいのですがどうすればいいですか？

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String endStr;          //読み込みを終了する文字列
        endStr = new String("end");
        StringBuilder strBul;   //組み立てた文字列
        strBul = new StringBuilder();
        String str;
        System.out.print("文字列を入力 : ");
        str = sc.next();
        while (str.equals(endStr) != true)
        {
            **strBul.append(str);**

            System.out.println("[組み立てた文字列] " + strBul);
            System.out.print("文字列を入力");
            str = sc.next();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

このプログラムのループ文の中の、太字、strBul.append(str);だと前ではなく後に結合してしまうので、どうしたら前に結合することはできますか？

～実行例～
文字列を入力 : board   
[組み立てた文字列] board
文字列を入力 : snow
[組み立てた文字列] snowboard
文字列を入力 : end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert` メソッドを使います。
`strBul.insert(0, str);`のようにすると先頭(`0`は挿入位置)に差し込むことができます。

Comment: できました！！
助かりました＾＾
ありがとうございます！